# allow .html and usernames to access via browsers using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm tying to edit `.htacess` file so i can allow two things to access via browsers

1. Any .html file
2. url like this `https://website.com/username`

I tried using this but this is not allowing to access .html files

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 ^(.*\. (html)$|index.php|favicon.png)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|css|js)$ - [L]

# No rewriting
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[R]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The `RewriteCond $1 ^(.*\. (html)$|index.php|favicon.png)` will cause an error

Comment: Can you please send me correct code to get fix the problem? I will really appreciate